# configure codeship to run when non-contributors make pull requests

Tags: continuous-integration, codeship

Default behavior for Codeship appears to be to only run CI against pull requests from existing contributors, not from people outside the organization. How do you change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Codeship doesn't support running tests against pull requests from people outside the organization.

From the Codeship FAQ (*emphasis added*):

> ### Testing PRs from Forked Repositories
>
> *Codeship does not support testing pull requests from forked
> repositories at the moment.* You’d need to configure the forked
> repository separately on Codeship or push the branch to the already
> configured repository instead.

https://codeship.com/documentation/faq/testing-prs-from-forked-repositories/